# Change element css based on contents through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have a vertical menu that is coded like this:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item">
  <a href="/page1">Page1</a>
 </li>
 <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item">
  <a href="/page2"> </a>
 </li>
 <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item">
  <a href="/page3">Page3</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, the anchor element to page2 doesn't contain any text. Therefore, I want to hide it from the menu. So I'm looking for a javascript solution that does something like this:

```
if (content of anchor tag equals " ") then 
set anchor's parent list element css to visiblity:hidden;
```

Note that I can't use document.getElementById on this one because the list id's are automatically generated and may change over time. So how do I get to the content of the anchor tag and set the correct list item's CSS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var link=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<link.length;i++)
if(link[i].innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")==='')
link[i].parentNode.style.display="hidden";
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JUcvj/1/)**

Comment: Almost. I think he wants to hide the parent `<li>`.

Comment: This works indeed very well on jsfiddle, even if I post the entire HTML of my webpage on there. Yet, on the real website it does not... Trying to figure out why now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getElementByTagName('li')` and then test that `class="menu-item'`

See this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/corinnekm/JUcvj/).

Comment: Jsfiddle does exactly what I want, so +1 for that. For some reason it doesn't work on my web page though, but I'm working on that. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can do something like:

```
$("li").each(function() { 
  if ($(this).find("a").text() == "") 
    {
     $(this).css('display','none');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this..

```
$('.sub-menu a').each(function () {
    if (this.innerHTML == " ") {
        this.parentNode.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
})
```